# i have a problem with this HttpGet method, i´ve used it before

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crud

I have used the same on a different Controller in the same folder. but this should not affect this? When i run the code it shows a SQLite error 1 message [image: Image of error here.]
My goal is to have the user to fill in a form and the input is transfered to the Database.

```
namespace findAMusicianApi.Controllers {
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MissionsController : ControllerBase{
        
        private readonly FindAMusicianContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hosting;
        public MissionsController( FindAMusicianContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hosting ){
            _context = context;
            _hosting = hosting;
        }

        [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IEnumerable<Missions>> Get(){
                List<Missions> missionList = await _context.Missions.ToListAsync();
                return missionList;
            }
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory; your `Missions` class has a `Descriptions` property (or another property mapped to that name) but here is no corresponding column in the database.

Comment: @YoungSushi, check your Mission class against the Mission table in your database, does this `Description` existed as the column in the database table?

Comment: i cant find the classes in the database no.. is there an update needed to the database ?

Comment: Problem solved, i had to run "dotnet ef migrations add classes" in Commandline.. and then do "dotnet ef database update". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the Missions model is the representation of the DB table.
The error says that you have a column named "Description" that is not present in the Missions Model.

Make sure that the Missions mode have all the properties needed to the deseralization process.

Comment: Problem solved, i had to run "dotnet ef migrations add classes" in Commandline.. and then do "dotnet ef database update". Thanks for the help!